# python flask sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying now about two hours to fix this problem. I know there are already alot of topics about this, but none of them is helping me.

I am using python and flask to run my apache2 server.

in this folder is my .wsgi file and my database.
/var/www/html/webApp

i gave the whole folder and the data base rights with:

```
chmod 777 /var/www/html/webApp
chmod 777 /var/www/html/webApp/users.sqlite3
```

i restarted after these comments the vps and the apache2 server multiple times, but still i am geting this error.

I really hope someone can help me.

regards

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same issue, could resolve it with help from the following page:
[sqlite3.OperationalError](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/sql/sqlite3.OperationalError%3A+attempt+to+write+a+readonly+database)

```
//do the follow
chown www-data /myproject
chown www-data /myproject/db.sqlite3
chmod 777 /myproject/db.sqlite3
```

The folder containing the db-file and the db-file itself must be owned by www-data. Otherwise the flask-application has no rights to change the db-file.